# Using INSERT INTO with Rich Text

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a from with a Rich Text box and a table with a rich Text field. I am trying use INSERT INTO to copy the text in the form to the table. All of my fields work great except the Rich Text file. I am not sure how to format the INSERT INTO string. Here is what I have tried.

```
DIM RT as String
RT = Me.RTBox
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTbl (RTField) VALUES (""" & RT & """);" 'Tried triple quotes
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTbl (RTField) VALUES ('" & RT & "');" 'Tried string quotes
```

Nothing seems to work. Please can someone tell me how I should be bracketing the variable. I have several field that I am inserting as well. Date, time and other non Rich Text fields. The other all work fine.

Comment: *Nothing seems to work* ... is not helpful for us. Tell us the specific error or undesired result of your code.

Comment: There is no error. It just inserts all of my fields except the rich text field. It is just empty. However, when I do a Debug.Print in the Immediate window, I am capturing the text, it is just not making it to the table.

Comment: What is the data type of *RTField*? Long or short text?

Answer (score 1):

```
RT = Me.RTBox
```

Sets the entire control to the RT variable
You want just the value that is in the control, try

```
RT = Me.RTBox.Value
```

P.S. Consider using

```
Option Explicit
```

At the top of your modules to ensure type compatibility. Using this would catch the error when you compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with *DAO*:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset    
Dim RT As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select RTField From MyTbl")
RT = Me!RTBox.Value

rs.AddNew
    rs!RTField.Value = RT
    ' or simply:
    ' rs!RTField.Value = Me!RTBox.Value
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTbl (RTField) VALUES ('''' & RT & '''');"  -- Quad Ticks for a single tick. (i believe)
```